# Redis streaming LIST responses

Tags: javascript, redis

We'd like to get a *response* from Redis as a *stream*, similar to [Postgres Streams](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query-stream).

We've got a constraint to use as little server memory as possible. Some of our Lists can be ~10MB and requested *simultaneously* from multiple users.

Doing this the ol-fashioned way *will* eventually cause memory problems on our servers.

An alternative solution is to iterate the list and send `lrange` commands, each batch returning a portion of the list items but that would be innefficient due to the network roundtrips.

Here's what I have for now, which is the standard way of doing things:

```
'use strict'

const redis = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient()

client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error ' + err)
})

client.rpush('foo', 1)
client.rpush('foo', 2)
client.rpush('foo', 3)
client.rpush('foo', 4)
client.rpush('foo', 5)

client.lrange('foo', 0, -1, (err, replies) => {
  console.log(replies)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming is not yet implemented in Redis, so pagination is a good approach. That said, the List data structure does not support that pattern too well as `LRANGE` is an expensive (O(N)) operation.

I suggest you consider an alternative data structure like Sorted Sets or the v5 Streams for storing your data.